Octomap Saving Map Extension - ROS2
After creating the map, I tried to save it using the following commands:
ros2 run octomap_server octomap_saver_node -f myfile.ot
ros2 run octomap_server octomap_saver_node -f myfile.bt

Both give me the following invalid extension error:
[ERROR] [1713233485.728582413] [octomap_saver]: Invalid file name or extension: 

I kindly request your help. Thanks!

Have you tried this process to save the map? https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/issues/876#issuecomment-1407534728

Thank you very much!

Your welcome, did this answer solved your problem? If yes tell me to add it as an answer

Yup, please add it as the answer. Thanks

As mentioned here, try this approach:
ros2 run octomap_server octomap_saver_node --ros-args -p octomap_path:=map.bt 
[INFO] [1674957009.554208229] [octomap_saver]: Map received (3516 nodes, 0.050000 m res), saving to map.bt

by default the service name is /octomap_binary. If rtabmap is in rtabmap namespace, you have to remap the service name:
ros2 run octomap_server octomap_saver_node --ros-args -p octomap_path:=map.bt -r octomap_binary:=/rtabmap/octomap_binary

To list all services:
ros2 service list | grep octomap

